# getting error while trying to run docker image

Tags: docker

I have hypriot OS installed on Raspberry pi 
I pulled the docker image but when trying to run it I am getting the below error of which I have no clue:

```
docker run fbender/php54-apache-mysql
panic: standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error" [recovered]
    panic: standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error"

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
panic(0x3360b0, 0x56ec4a40)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x330
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction.func1(0x56ec1958)
    /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:478 +0x328
panic(0x3360b0, 0x56ec4a40)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x448
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory).StartInitialization.func1(0x56ec15e0, 0x56e0e280, 0x56ec1668)
    /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go:259 +0x13c
github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory).StartInitialization(0x56e88270, 0x46464490, 0x56ec4a40)
    /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go:277 +0x498
main.glob.func8(0x56e7c320, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/main_unix.go:26 +0x58
reflect.Value.call(0x2eb600, 0x3f2948, 0x13, 0x3648b8, 0x4, 0x56ec1918, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:435 +0xeb4
reflect.Value.Call(0x2eb600, 0x3f2948, 0x13, 0x56ec1918, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:303 +0x84
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction(0x2eb600, 0x3f2948, 0x56e7c320, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:487 +0x230
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run(0x366cd8, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3d0d50, 0x51, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/command.go:191 +0xcd0
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run(0x56e74240, 0x56e56050, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:240 +0x84c
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/main.go:137 +0xbb4
```

Comment: Did you edit any of the files on windows before running them on the Pi?

Comment: no, i do not edit any file, I just pulled and then I tried running

Comment: This post possibly describes your issue: https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/255163/exec-format-error-wetek-hub-with-libreelec
It is possible that the images can run only on intel64 and not on arm64. Just a guess anyway